# Return entire object from Array based on key value in object using jq

Tags: arrays, json, linux, sorting, jq

I have a .json file that I would like to filter through jq to return the entire object in the array if the key value in that object equals 'failed'. How would I do this  ?

Example json:

```
"version": "0.26.0",
"controls": [{
    "id": "os-1.0",
    "status": "passed",
    "code_desc": "File /etc/profile content should match /umask\\s*022/",
    "profile_id": "test"
}, {
    "id": "os-1.0",
    "status": "passed",
    "code_desc": "File /etc/bashrc content should match /umask\\s*022/",
    "profile_id": "test"
}, {
    "id": "os-1.0",
    "status": "failed",
    "code_desc": "File /etc/csh.cshrc content should match /umask\\s*022/",
    "profile_id": "test"
   "message": "\nexpected: \"/sbin/sulogin\"\n     got: \n\n(compared using `cmp` matcher)\n"
}]
```

Output to a new file :

```
{
    "id": "os-1.0",
    "status": "failed",
    "code_desc": "File /etc/csh.cshrc content should match /umask\\s*022/",
    "profile_id": "test"
    "message": "\nexpected: \"/sbin/sulogin\"\n     got: \n\n(compared using  `cmp` matcher)\n"
}
```

Comment: can you please try https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#filter-objects-based-on-the-contents-of-a-key

Comment: @BhavinSolanki This is what I've tried so far : cat file.json | jq -c '.[] | select(.controls | . and contains("failure"))' but I believe I'm missing an array coordinate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text shown as JSON is invalid as JSON.  Assuming it is fixed to have
the structure `{"version": _, "controls": _}`, the following filter
would yield the result shown below:

```
.controls[] | select(.status == "failed")
```

Output:

```
{
  "id": "os-1.0",
  "status": "failed",
  "code_desc": "File /etc/csh.cshrc content should match /umask\\s*022/",
  "profile_id": "test",
  "message": "\nexpected: \"/sbin/sulogin\"\n     got: \n\n(compared using `cmp` matcher)\n"
}
```

Note: For robustness you might want to use `.status?` instead of `.status`.